# why isn't my website responsive on mobile view?

Tags: css, iphone, url, mobile, responsive-design

The website I'm having problems with is "kayparkmemorials.com". If you view it on your laptop/desktop, and you scale the website down to your smallest possible scalable window, it appears to function as expected responsively. For some reason, when I view the site on my mobile phone, it displays the view as if it's in tablet view.

I have the max-width for mobile view set as: @media screen and (max-width: 815px)

Anyone had any previous issues similar to this and have some tips? Another important thing I should add is that when testing the site on Dreamweaver by scanning the barcode to get the preview on my mobile, it previewed as expected. I didn't change anything to the coding after that point and as soon as it is officially on the web (1&1 HOSTING), the responsiveness on mobile isn't doing what it should.

Comment: Check the default zoom on your browser on your phone, I'd bargain it's not `100%` and that's why you're getting unexpected results. Your Desktop browser is most likely by default `100%` (unless you're running IE11 which is `110%` I believe). You may find you need to force the browser resolution/scaling to `100%` using Javascript or have some _additional_ `@media` handling for _actual_ mobile viewing .

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a viewport meta tag to the head of your page, if you don't do this the default behaviour for smart phone browsers is to scale your desktop page.

What you want is

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
...  
</head>
```

Good luck!

Comment: You're an absolute lifesaver. That's exactly what the problem was. Fixed it straight away. Thank you so much!